# How do I change the entry widget state from disabled to not disabled by using a check box widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, state, tkinter-entry

I am using tkinter 8.6 with python 3.5.2 and I trying to create a GUI so that when I click a check box it allows a user to write something into an entry box. However I am getting an error. Below is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def quit():
    mainframe.quit()

#Write in Function
def write():
    write_in.state(['!disabled']) #Getting Error Here

root = Tk()
root.title("Voting Booth")

#Global variables
var = StringVar()

#Create main widget
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S)) 
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

#Additional widgets
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=var, font=('bold')).grid(column=2, row=0)
vote = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Vote", command = quit).grid(column=4, row=5, sticky=E)
don_box = ttk.Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Donald Trump").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)
stein_box = ttk.Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Jill Stein").grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=W)
write_box = ttk.Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Write in:", command = write).grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=W)
write_in = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 20, state=DISABLED).grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=W)

#Setting variables and widgets
var.set("Presidential Nominees")

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop();
```

However I am getting the following error when I click the write_in checkbox:

```
" File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "./booth_gui.py", line 13, in write
write_in.state(['!disabled'])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'state' "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `NoneType` exception because the `write_in` object is actually `None`.

The problem is that you declare `write_in` as:

```
write_in = ttk.Entry(...).grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=W)
```

But the `grid` method returns a `None` result.

The call to `grid` must be separated from the widget declaration:

```
write_in = ttk.Entry(...)
write_in.grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=W)
```

---

About the way you change the widget's state, I'm not really sure it is supposed to work.

Try with the `config` (or `configure`) widget method and set the `state` keyword to `NORMAL`:

```
write_in.config(state=NORMAL)
```

Comment: I have tried this but it still gave me an error when I clicked the checkbox, which calls the write function. I am not sure if I need to change the function itself or if I am not importing the correct libraries.

Comment: I was not sure, since I cannot use tkinter right now and I don't know ttk... What is the error it gives you? That `config` does not exist, or that `state` is not valid, or that `NORMAL` is not defined?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Comment: Try with `configure` instead. If it works, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Tried that as well and it still gave me the same error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure' "

Comment: This worked perfectly and thank you for the informative description as well. I really appreciate the speedy response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129959/discussion-between-right-leg-and-pdm).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.title('Voting Booth')

        self.labelvar = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.votevar = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.writevar = tkinter.StringVar()

        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        self.mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.label = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, textvariable=self.labelvar, font=('bold'))
        self.vote = ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text='Vote', command=self.quit)
        self.don_box = ttk.Radiobutton(self.mainframe, text='Donald Trump', variable=self.votevar, value='trump', command=self.write)
        self.stein_box = ttk.Radiobutton(self.mainframe, text='Jill Stein', variable=self.votevar, value='stein', command=self.write)
        self.write_box = ttk.Radiobutton(self.mainframe, text='Write in: ', variable=self.votevar, value='write', command=self.write)
        self.write_in = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe, textvariable= self.writevar, width=20, state='disabled')

        self.label.grid(column=2, row=0)
        self.vote.grid(column=4, row=5, sticky='e')
        self.don_box.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky='w')
        self.stein_box.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky='w')
        self.write_box.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky='w')
        self.write_in.grid(column=3, row=4, stick='w')

        self.labelvar.set('Presidential Nominees')

        for child in self.mainframe.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

    def quit(self):
        self.root.destroy()

    def write(self):
        if self.votevar.get() == 'write':
            self.write_in['state'] = 'normal'
        else:
            self.write_in['state'] = 'disabled'
            self.writevar.set('')

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at the following line: `self.vote = ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text='Vote', command=self.quit)` The error reads the following: `self.vote = ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text='Vote', command=self.quit)  AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'quit'`

Comment: Hmmm, I don't get that error. Maybe it is your editor? Also check to make sure that you copied the entire source.